# A cleaning gone very wrong

Tags: windows, images, cleaning

I had intended to help a friend with cleaning out her family's computer. I have a bit of tech expierence myself having upgraded and regularly cleaning my own but this is just random as hell. I turned the computer on its side to clean it with the compressed air to get the dust out. I did not remove or unplug a thing. Turned it back upright...It turns on but the monitor says there is no signal. As if something with the graphics card is now having an issue or something.

Comment: did you make sure the connections (cables both ends) are secure? Something could have become loose on the outside that is........ turning a computer on its side and back should not have caused the gfx card itself from not working unless something became loose. Which is mostly likely a cable.

Comment: If there are removable cards in the box, unplug and replug them (WITH THE POWER OFF AND THE UNIT UNPLUGGED.)

Answer (score 2):

If the card was working before you moved the computer, most likely its still working.  Its not uncommon after physically moving a PC for a loose cable or card to *look* connected, but not be properly seated.  I would suggest making sure every cable is properly and securely connected.  Same thing for all the add on cards.  I would even go as far as to remove and reinstall the graphics card to make sure its seated properly in the slot and the power and graphics cables are connected and well seated.